# TypeError: evt.target is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-saga

I have tried to implement an AutoComplete Input Field. The corresponding documentation can be found [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/autocomplete). If more code is needed, please let me know. However, the code involved is kind of long and I didn't want to put it all here.

### Error:

Don't be surprised if it says 1 of 2 errors above, but for whatever reason the same error message is displayed twice.

[image]

### My Code:

#### `AlarmstichworteAutocompleteForm/index.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { memo } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { AutoComplete } from 'primereact/autocomplete';
import { messages } from './messages';
import {
  selectSuggestionInput,
  selectData,
  selectLoading,
  selectError,
} from './slice/selectors';
import {getAlarmstichworte} from './slice/saga';
import { AlarmstichwortErrorType } from './slice/types';
import { useAlarmstichworteAutocompleteFormSlice } from './slice';
import { fetchAlarmstichworte, fetchAlarmstichworteByName } from './slice/api';
import { Alarmstichwort } from '../../../../../../../types/Alarmstichwort';
import { lazyLoad } from '../../../../../../../utils/loadable';

interface Props {}

export const AlarmstichworteAutocompleteForm= memo((props: Props) => {

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  const {t,  i18n } = useTranslation();
  const {actions} = useAlarmstichworteAutocompleteFormSlice();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const suggestionInput = useSelector(selectSuggestionInput);
  const data = useSelector(selectData);
  const loading = useSelector(selectLoading);
  const error = useSelector(selectError);

  const useEffectOnMount = (effect: React.EffectCallback) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    useEffect(effect, []);
  };

  const onChangeSuggestionInput = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    dispatch(actions.changeSuggestionInput(evt.target.value)); // <-- Part of the error
    dispatch(actions.loadAlarmstichworte());
  };


  useEffectOnMount(() => {
    dispatch(actions.loadAlarmstichworte());
  });

  return(
    <div>
      <AutoComplete 
      dropdown 
      value={suggestionInput}
      suggestions={data} 
      onChange={(evt) => onChangeSuggestionInput(evt.value)} // <-- Part of the error
      />
    </div>
   
    );
});
```

The idea behind it is the following: When input is entered into the input field, the action `changeSuggestionInput` adds the suggestionInput to the state. When `actions.loadAlarmstichworte` is run again, only the results matching the API search input with the suggestionInput are displayed.

### Update:

If I replace `onChange={(evt) => onChangeSuggestionInput(evt.value)}` with `onChange={onChangeSuggestionInput}` I get the following error:

````
`No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: AutoCompleteProps | Readonly<AutoCompleteProps>): AutoComplete', gave the following error.
    Type '(evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(e: AutoCompleteChangeParams) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'evt' and 'e' are incompatible.
        Type 'AutoCompleteChangeParams' is missing the following properties from type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>': nativeEvent, currentTarget, bubbles, cancelable, and 8 more.   
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: AutoCompleteProps, context: any): AutoComplete', gave the following error.
    Type '(evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(e: AutoCompleteChangeParams) => void'.  TS2769```
````

Comment: You do not want to send `evt.value` to `onChangeSuggestionInput` but rather the entire event element, then inside `onChangeSuggestionInput` you can make variables to extract from `evt` the value, the target or whatever you need to use

Answer (score 1):

The error lies here.

```
 <AutoComplete 
      dropdown 
      value={suggestionInput}
      suggestions={data} 
      onChange={(evt) => onChangeSuggestionInput(evt.value)} 
      />
```

Here `evt.value` is passed as a param.

```
 const onChangeSuggestionInput = (evt:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)
```

And here in this function, you are accessing `evt.target`.

You can remove the bug at the calling part.

```
    onChange={onChangeSuggestionInput}
```

Comment: If i do it this way i get the error i added above in the post.

Comment: It's the equivalent of `onChange={(evt) => onChangeSuggestionInput(evt)}`. If this does not work, then you can check the `AutoComplete` whether or not you need to use `onChange` or sth else to detect input change.

Comment: I still can't find the exact error, as according to the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/autocomplete) `onChange` should be specified but I'll keep looking. Thanks for the help!